# Joomla - how to get category id in the url

Tags: url, joomla, menu

i rebuild a new joomla site from 1.5 to 3.2.
now i have the following problem:

at the old blog section(joomla 1.5) joomla create this url:
/blog/54-blog/82-name.html

but on the new joomla 3.2 installation, joomla create this url:
/blog/82-artikelname.html

How can i create the old url structure with the category id in it?

cheers
jan

Comment: Is `54-blog` a category reference? Menu references don't typically have an index number in them.

Comment: yeah you are right, this is a category id not a menu id

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a menu link directly to the 54-blog category, make a menu item to list categories (it should contain the blog category), then when you click on the blog category in the frontend it should display the old way, with the categoryId-categoryAlias.

If Joomla finds a menu item referencing that category in the menu list, then it won't show the id as a prefix of the alias.

Comment: This should work. I often create a separate menu just for this type of thing. Put an item in it which is a blog layout for that category. Like marcanuy says, that should result in the category in the URLs.

Comment: hmm ok, maybe i dont get it.
i create an other menu item in an nother menu with and the Menu Item Type is "List All Categories" and than i select the Blog category!?